# NVD3 PieChart tooltips not shown

Tags: filter, tooltip, legend, nvd3.js, pie-chart

I've got some problems with nvd3 pie chart.
I tried this example:

`Example` http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/30rm9qk7/

I've added nv.d3.min and nv.d3.css to my application.
This example looks fine, but there are two problems.

1) No tooltips are shown.
Also the content of the tooltips is not added in DOM.

2) Click on the legend does not filter. Nothing happend.

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps missing .js?

This is my code:

```
    private native void createTestPieChart()/*-{
    function pieSectorData() {
        return [ {
            "key" : "Technology",
            y : 298.85,
            "symbols" : "DOV",
            "color" : "#3182bd",
        },

        {
            "key" : "Health Care",
            y : 477.80,
            "symbols" : "JNJ",
            "color" : "#6baed6",
        },

        {
            "key" : "Consumer Services",
            y : 485.65,
            "symbols" : "MCD",
            "color" : "#9ecae1",
        },

        {
            "key" : "Energy",
            y : 739.45,
            "symbols" : "XOM, CVX",
            "color" : "#A52A2A",
        } ];
    }

    //Regular pie chart example
    $wnd.nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = $wnd.nv.models.pieChart().x(function(d) {
            return d.key
        }).y(function(d) {
            return d.y
        }).showLabels(true).color(function(d) {
            return d.color;
        }).showLegend(true);

        chart.tooltip.keyFormatter(function(d, i) {
            var symbol = '';
            pieSectorData().forEach(function(entry) {
                // Search data for key and return the symbols
                if (entry.key == d) {
                    symbol = entry.symbols
                }
            });
            return d + '(' + symbol + ')'
        });

        $wnd.d3.select("#piechart svg").datum(pieSectorData()).transition()
                .duration(350).call(chart);

        return chart;
    });

}-*/;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is very difficult to diagnose without seeing a working example. Are you getting any javascript errors? Are you using exactly the same code as in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you add the code you have been working on, so we could identify the problem. Make sure you are using the correct version of NVD3 JS & CSS.

Comment: I use exactly the same code as in jsfiddle. The CSS in my html file is nv.d3.min.css and the JS stream_layers.js, d3.v3.min.js, nv.d3.min.js and topojson.v1.min.js.

Comment: There are no javascript errors.

Comment: @Kobi can you put your code on a a fiddle so someone could help you out.